# php: variables in strings

Tags: php, variables

I need to use strings that contains variables that have to be interpreted after the definition of the string.

```
    $mystring = "aaa".{$i};
    ...
    $i=3;
    echo $mystring; //Expected result: aaa3
```

Is it possible to load into $mystring not the value of the variable but only the name of the variable, so that its value can be loaded later?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this for code obfuscation or avoiding arrays? (Why?) -- And since the output is `AAA.$i` you'd probably have to look at the initial value declaration.

Comment: but what you get from it?

Comment: Avoid having variable variables as far as possible.

Comment: If you want the `$i` in `$comA = "AAA.\$i";`  to automatically have the value 3, then sorry, it's not possible as it does the replacement immediately. It is not like pass by reference as you think.

Comment: @vivek_23 sir the `OP` wants its output  `AAA3` is it possible from this code?

Comment: @KUMAR Like the code shown in the link, it's possible. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b01459eb6e2a80bef9a7d00b2ab260f7a90986d

Comment: @vivek_23 yes sir thanks.

Comment: A bit of a shame this is closed.  I read this as wanting to embed a reference in a string.  You could ape it with a bit of a laborious workaround: https://3v4l.org/KMbIQ

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusing question. If you want the result to be AAA3, then the code should be:

```
$i=3;
$com="AAA";
echo $variable = $com.$i;
```

Comment: Simple enough. Avoid using variable variables as much as you can

Comment: I have tried with vectors and it does not work either.